# Netty Channel says remote address is "embedded". How can I find the originator?

Tags: java, netty

I have a couple different very complex Netty 4 based processes that have lots of incoming and outgoing connections. In a certain case, I have about a dozen running on one machine.

I have my own handler and pipeline, and in the handler, I query the ChannelHandlerContext to log the remote end of a set of requests.

Normally I do something like this:

```
public void handle(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest request){
    System.out.println(ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress());
}
```

In this case, the remote address is of type EmbeddedSocketAddress, and returns just "embedded".

In normal cases, I can get the IP/Port from the InetSocketAddress and use lsof to find out who's making the call. In this case, I can't.

How can I find out what/who is calling into my handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out where these are coming from. The framework that creates my pipeline runs a "warm up" routine that injects these requests right into the pipeline without a remote end. I apologize for my idiocy.

Comment: Inevitably, the best way to find an answer is to beat my head for hours, then ask on SO. All is then revealed, and I bask in my own stupidity :/